# SonarQube: avoid counting comments percentage for getters and setter in java

Tags: java, sonarqube, comments, getter-setter, sonarqube-5.4

After searching for a while here and in the web I found the property sonar.squid.analyse.property.accessors which was documentated here:
https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Metrics+-+Public+API

This looks like what we want but the documentation is outdated. In the current documentation this property is not mentioned any more.

We have in some big java projects a lot of utility classes which usually only contains properties with their corresponding getters and setter methods.

This is drawing our percentage of comments down just remarkably.

Is there a way (besides adding //NOSONAR to every method or excluding all files manually by configuration) to avoid counting missing comments in the getter/setter-methods to the comments percentage?

Comment: If by "comments" you mean Javadoc comments, it isn't SonarQube that's dragging your stats down, but your neglect of Javadoc comments. If you didn't neglect writing Javadocs your stats would be where they belong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The property `sonar.squid.analyse.property.accessors` was dropped in a previous version of SonarJava (and dropped from the documentation as well). 
As such the getters and setters were counted as undocumented API but this has been fixed already: 
https://jira.sonarsource.com/browse/SONARJAVA-1857

Please consider upgrading SonarJava to the latest version (4.6 at time of writing, requiring SonarQube LTS 5.6 and java 8 )

Comment: Ok. I now have SonarQube 5.6 and SonarJava 4.6. Result is still the same.

Comment: Classes with only class comment, private fileds and their corresponding getters/setters are shown as "Comments (%): 0,8" or likewise less. I now understand that I am using the wrong metric. With "Public Documented API (%)" it works. Thanks for the answer.